# Sulu: How to display single_select as select instead of radio input?

Tags: sulu

is there a way to display a single_select in sulu admin as select box instead of a radio input?

I have a definition like this:

```
<property name="imagePosition" type="single_select" colspan="6">
    <params>
        <param name="values" type="collection">
            <param name="left">
                <meta>
                    <title lang="en">Left</title>
                </meta>
            </param>
            <param name="right">
                <meta>
                    <title lang="en">Right</title>
                </meta>
            </param>
            <param name="top">
                <meta>
                    <title lang="en">Top</title>
                </meta>
            </param>
            <param name="bottom">
                <meta>
                    <title lang="en">Bottom</title>
                </meta>
            </param>
            <param name="afterHeadline">
                <meta>
                    <title lang="en">After Headline</title>
                </meta>
            </param>
        </param>
    </params>
</property>
```

Maybe something like `<param name="values" type="collection" input="select">`?

Thx a lot!
Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create you custom template for rendering `single_select` type and specify this template in SuluContentBundle configuration

```
sulu_content:
    types:
        single_select:
            template: 'AppBundle:admin:single_select.html.twig'
```

More detailed instruction: [Display single_select as select instead of radio input on Sulu admin](https://yasa.tatar/display-single-select-as-select-instead-of-radio-input-on-sulu-admin)

Comment: Mate, this looks awesome! I'll give it a try and if it works, I'll change the accepted answer.

Comment: Validated and works perfectly! The slect should have `class="form-element"` thou ;).

Comment: Ok, I can not edit my comment anymore, the select tag should look like this, to fully integrate with the framework: `<select id="{{ id|raw }}" name="{{ id|raw }}" class="preview-update trigger-save-button form-element" data-property='{{ property|json_encode }}' data-mapper-property="{{ property.name }}">`

Comment: Thanks, i fixed the instruction by your comment.

Answer (score 0):

That is not implemented yet... So I am afraid to say that this is not working :-/

Comment: No worries - if I find some time I'll create a PR for that, probably as `<param name="input_type" value="select"/>` with default radio?

Comment: There was also the suggestion to create an own content type based on 'single_select' but with your ones own twig template. In case somenody needs this urgently